# Robot Framework - Best Element to use on dynamic web app

Tags: css, robotframework, webautomation

Im writing a RF script for a dynamic site.. However,based on user permissions the menu tabs change/hide. I cant use xpath since the order of the tabs might change. any suggestions. CSS and Sizzle dont seem to work great since I couldnt find and id or name values being used.

Not sure if below helps

```
<div class="interior_nav_lv2" id="div_2_1" style="display: block;">

                        <a class="subNavOffHREF " href="index.cfm?view=something.sCs">Search Cardholders</a>

                        <a class="subNavOffHREF " href="index.cfm?view=something.lCs">List Cardholders</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Clicking links

You can use the link text as a locator if you need to click one of the links. For example:

```
click link    Send Message
```

You can also explicitly include the locator strategy:

```
click link    link=Send Message
```

This is all documented under the section titled "Locating or specifying elements" in the [Selenium2Library documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html).

And contrary to what is stated in your question, you *can* use xpath. For example, this works:

```
click link    xpath=//a[text()='Add Cardholder']
```

### Getting a list of links

If you need to validate the links, you can use [Get Webelements](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Webelements) to get all of the links.  You can then iterate over the links to save the link text. For example:

```
${elements}=    get webelements    xpath=//div[@class='interior_nav_lv2']/a
@{links}=  create list
:FOR  ${element}  IN  @{elements}
\    append to list  ${links}  ${element.text}

Should contain  ${links}  Search Cardholders
Should contain  ${links}  List Cardholders
```